# Python- Create a background timer process ,not involving tkinter's "after"

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make a generic countdown timer. If was GUI based, using `tk.after` would do the magic, but it is not.

During given time interval, should it returns `1` when countdown in progress and `0` when it is off. This counter will run in background **inside** other classes (that may be GUI class).

for example, let `TimeOut` be that countdown timer:

```
a = TimeOut(days=0,seconds=100) # a runs in background for 100 seconds.
a.status() # during countdown time - `status` returns `1`.
```

Is there an elegant way to create such class?

Comment: How do not expect `class TimeOut` to not use `tkinter` if it's derived from the `tkinter.Frame` class? It also has a number of other dependencies. Please define exactly what methods the independent class is to have.

Comment: @martineau - I do not need any `tkinter` dependncy it was only for example. you can see at upper part of my question what is needed: time interval, and output, 0 or 1

Comment: You could make a function with time.sleep(seconds).

Comment: @Nae as I wrote- it should run in backgroud, using sleep, will pause entire code for that time

Comment: Guy: You shouldn't use `sleep()` in a tkinter program because it will hang the GUI's `mainloop()` at it won't respond to user input for the duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with tkinter.

Use a `threading.Timer`.

```
>>> from threading import Timer
>>> t = Timer(10, lambda: None)
>>> t.start()
>>> t.is_alive() # call before 10 seconds is up
True
>>> t.is_alive() # call after 10 seconds is up
False
```